# How to launch Microsoft Store automatically in python or powerShell script?

Tags: python, powershell, scripting

I want to be able to run the script which will launch App store automatically. I am able to launch Notepad etc. but not Microsoft Store. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Think that your main issue revolves around non .exe files to execute. Perhaps the following link will work Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surprisingly simple to do from PowerShell. This command will do it:

```
Start-Process ms-windows-store:
```

Comment: If this answer resolved the problem please mark it as accepted to help future users with the same question find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a library like pyautogui to physically press the windows button and then type "windows store" and press enter. 
The code would be something like this:

```
import pyautogui as gui
gui.press("win")
# delay maybe
gui.typewrite("windows store")
gui.press("enter")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!